How do I call a pods endpoint running on a service from a second service?
I have an api hosted on a kubernetes service that I am trying to call another service that connects me to a database. If I call the api that is hosted on my db-daemon pod, I get a good response. I can also ping the pod from another pod, and I always receive the packets back. However when I try calling the endpoint of the db_service on port 8081 (which should be forwarding to 19091 on the pod), I get
Error: error connecting to the daemon: dial tcp 10.104.84.168:8081: connect: connection refused

In my code, I call the db-service with a tcp call to "db-service:8081"
The same thing happens if I call the <pod_ip>:19091 directly, so I believe the disconnect is something with permissions somewhere, but I am not sure.
What am I missing to connect the two services?
Here is my .yml file with the relevant information. I am pretty new to kubernetes, so let me know if there is anything I am missing, or if additional information could help.
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: test-defintion-server
  labels:
    app: test-defintion-server
spec:
  replicas: 3  
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: test-defintion-server
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: test-defintion-server
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: api
          image: localhost:5000/server_api:v0.0.2  
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8080  
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-load-balanced-service
  labels:
    app: test-defintion-server
spec:
  selector:
    app: test-defintion-server
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 8080
  type: LoadBalancer
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: db-service
  labels: 
    app: db-service
spec:
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 8081   
      targetPort: 19091
  selector:
   app: db-daemon

  type: ClusterIP 

---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: db-daemon
  labels:
    app: db-daemon
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
   matchLabels:
      app:  db-daemon
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: db-daemon
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: db-daemon
          image: localhost:5000/db_service:v0.0.1
          ports:
            - containerPort: 19091 


The Service's selector: doesn't match any of the Pods' metadata: { labels: }.  That can lead to the Service just not starting a network listener inside the cluster, and you'll get a "connection refused" error like that.

I do not see any issues so far in your YAML manifest you have provided. When you have the db and test-definition servers deployed, can you reach the db with kubectl port-forward <DB POD NAME> -n <NAMESPACE> 19091:19091 for example?

@Ryan, yes this reaches the db as it should

@DavidMaze Thanks, I updated the YAML, but still the same results

from the server pod can you try nc -zv db-service.<NAMESPACE>.svc.cluster.local 8081? I suppose you are not using the dns name <SERVICE_NAME>.<NAMESPACE>.svc.cluster.local in your code.

@Ryan I get a connection refused response. My services are both in the default namespace and so I just call the endpoint in my code as "db-servce:8081". From my understanding that should default it using a connection to whatever ip address the db-service is on, correct?

It also gets an immediate rejection, but when I try other ports it hangs for alittle while and returns with a ? instead of tproxy. Is it possible this a firewall issue on my local machine?

I am not aware whether db-service:8081 could work in the same namespace - I do not think that will work (but someone else can correct me if this is not the case). I doubt it is a firewall issue. By any chance do you network policy resources?

Your db-service Service is of type ClusterIP. That's why you are not able to reach it from external access point.

I can also ping the pod from another pod, and I always receive the packets back

For this same reason, you are able to reach that from another pod within the cluster.

While it is true that I can't reach the ClusterIP from outside the k8s cluster, my problem is that I still can't reach the db-daemon running on port 8081 from another pod(the one with the api running on it) in the same cluster, so this doesn't answer my question.
